# Offline emulator for Google glass OS

Tags: emulation, google-glass

I've found an online [google glass emulator](http://glasssim.com/). Who knows does (or will) google provide any offline emulator for developers?

Comment: The link you posted is not an emulator, rather a tool for conceptualizing an app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Glass team is looking to provide an offline emulator for Glass, but this does not change the fact that you need Glass to develop for Glass. PY stated this at [Google I/O 2013 - Voiding Your Warranty: Hacking Glass (33:40)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPethpwuYEk&t=33m40s).

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/Scarygami/mirror-api it runs off GAE offline and it strings together Google's other existing API's.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I answered similar question here: [Is there an Android based Google Glass Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19741679/462936)

I managed to install Glass APKs into Nexus 7 tablet. All the required steps are here:
http://www.elekslabs.com/2013/11/google-glass-development-without-glass.html