# Google Glass Disabled in Android Studio after installing SDKs

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass, google-gdk

I installed Android Studio and the necessary SDKs for Google Glass Development, however, Glass is stilled disabled whenever I create new Android project?

Is it necessary that I have my own Google Glass device in order for this to work? I'm planning to use an emulator, though?

See the screenshots here:

[Screenshot 1:](https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/11057237_10153036451501969_1573199593743884047_n.jpg?oh=5607a25e54daeb4a9d17959a74add0ee&oe=5679C788&__gda__=1450977783_ed06b002f38e6a3fa9754934c20e588f)

[Screenshot 2:](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-9/11895950_10153036451396969_9059529251447104394_n.jpg?oh=554c0f9ac38c9a047e52acc7c973a7e7&oe=5683CA38&__gda__=1447088125_01a8db0b972725a3830152f91f7ebd48)

Comment: Make sure Android Studio is using the same sdk location (same path)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no official emulator for Google Glass.

If you really want to make glassware, you should consider buying Glass.

> Glass is stilled disabled whenever I create new Android project?

When you create Glass project, the SDK will be added as a dependency but that doesn't mean you have Glass emulator.

> Is it necessary that I have my own Google Glass device in order for this to work?

As of now, you need Google Glass for development. There is no official emulator.

> I'm planning to use an emulator, though?

Google hasn't released Glass emulator.

More info:

- [Is there an Android based Google Glass Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036245/is-there-an-android-based-google-glass-emulator)
- [Offline emulator for Google glass OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141262/offline-emulator-for-google-glass-os)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fixed the problem by installing again the latest version of Android studio.

Please don't edit the plist located in  `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/Info.plist` because is probably that doing this will break android studio.

Instead of doing that, open android studio this way, for example:

```
$ export STUDIO_JDK=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk 
$ open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/
```