# Can I build app for Google Glass using Eclipse with Emultaor?

Tags: eclipse, google-glass

Can I build own app for Google Glass without Google Glass( for debugging and testing)?

I have Eclipse.

I don't have Google Glass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build the application but there isn't an emulator. Someone else already asked about an emulator [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036245/is-there-an-android-based-google-glass-emulator). As for building your application, you're going to want to visit [The GDK Quick Start Guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start). Having eclipse is a good start.