# Google Glass : Launch AVD Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, google-glass

I want to run the sample app of Google Glass. I am using the Eclipse environment. I have already downloaded SDK platform and Glass Development Kit - Sneak Peak. But when I try to launch the Android Virtual Device Manager and select target as Glass Development Kit Sneak Peak, it does not launch.

What should I do ?

Comment: Viedee have you checked the console there should provide everything there? And also can you explain "it does not launch" ? Also can you provide the link of sample of you are trying to run. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The Android Virtual Device Manager is for emulators; it may not help because there is no officially supported Google Glass emulator. You may want to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036245/is-there-an-android-based-google-glass-emulator) for more information.