# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.glass.app.Card

Tags: google-glass

I am trying to create a sample glass application using below tools -

GDK Preview API 19
Java 6
Android 4.4.2

I have added an activity as below -

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Context con = this;
        Card myCard = new Card(con);
        myCard.setText("Hello, World!");         
        myCard.setFootnote("First Glassware for Glass"); 
        View cardView = myCard.getView();
        setContentView(cardView);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It gives an error for Card class not found, I have added the gdk.jar(21 KB) but still it throws an error. Please advise
Also I have checked the Card class code and its a stub class and does not contain implementation. Could you please provide correct gdk jar with correct implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a simple HelloWorld app, you can follow [THIS](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/06/tutorial-83-hello-world-using-google-glass/)

I got it to work just today just by doing so. Please see my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797536/hello-world-for-google-glass)

Comment: thanks, I am trying to create HelloWorld app only.I have tried to follow the links specified but still the issue persists. I am getting an exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!"

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Juno

Comment: Android sdk 19 and GDK Preview

Comment: No, I have created an AVD for Glass and trying to run on it. I can share the screenshots of the actual implementation but how can I upload it here ?

Comment: Have you used the same configuration and is it worked for you ?

Comment: I think the Exception is caused by not running it on Glass. I'm not sure GDK will work with non-glass device. Check out the post [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036245/is-there-an-android-based-google-glass-emulator)

Comment: Yes, I used the exact same code with the only exception to add the permission as shown in the link. And it worked.

Comment: So the difference is that you have executed it on glass and I am trying it on AVD emulator

Comment: I'd assume so given the information. Did the Card Class error still occur? You can try delete and re-install your Google Development Kit from SDK Manager, but I doubt that you can run Glass code just with AVD emulator.

Comment: Could you please confirm the size of the gdk.jar file size ? As this jar is creating an issue for my case. Does you gdk jar has the implementation or its a stub class holding jar?

Comment: How did you add your GDK? You should install it from SDK Manager. When you start a new project, set the Minimum and Require SDK to API19 and select GDK for "Compile With"

Comment: Yes, I have done the same thing, installed GDK from SDK manager and the minimum and require sdk to API 19 for new project and GDK for compilewith. How can I share my codebase? Is there any way where I can upload so you will get clear picture for issue ?

Comment: my email: masterofpudge@gmail.com

Comment: The static card we need to use through gdk jar only or we need to write our own implementation for it ?

Comment: through gdk. https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/Card