# How to create an Android base emulator for google glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I want to test google glass app in my local machine. Is there a way to test the app using android virtual device without actually having a google glass device ? I saw the same question in [Is there an Android based Google Glass Emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036245/is-there-an-android-based-google-glass-emulator), still isn't there an AVD?

Answer (score 0):

No, not the case. Probable you have read that Hololens SDK includes an emulator, good point from MS guys